# How to change segmentedBar selected tabview indicator color in Nativescript angular for android

Tags: nativescript, segment, nativescript-angular, nstabview

I am developing a cross-platform application using native-script angular.
In Android, I face the issue in the selected indicator colour in the segmented bar. Anyone Knows how to change the selected indicator colour in the segmented bar. It shows the default color blue.

```
<SegmentedBar #tabs [items]="myItems" selectedIndex="0" (selectedIndexChange)="onSelectedIndexChange(tabs.selectedIndex)" class="m-5" selectedBackgroundColor="gray" ></SegmentedBar>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Segemented bar add the property selectedBackgroundColor="gray"